# Source code for java.io.FileOutputStream.write(int, boolean) native method

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, native

As stated in the question, I'm looking for a source code for `java.io.FileOutputStream#write(int, boolean)` native method. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using OpenJDK 8. I already downloaded from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8 sources for OpenJDK 8 and also for OpenJDK 8 HotSpot project. I can find implementations of other native methods (e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis` or `System.arrayscopy`) but I cannot find `FileOutputStream.write(int, boolean)`.

I'm seeing plenty of libraries in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64`. Could you please let me know of all places that contain source code for Java runtime and help me find `FileOutputStream.write(int, boolean)` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two implementations, one for unix and one for Windows in a file called `src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/FileOutputStream_md.c` which both look like this.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_io_FileOutputStream_write(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jint byte, jboolean append) {
    writeSingle(env, this, byte, append, fos_fd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can find it in Java 9+ (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/FileOutputStream_md.c) but still don't see it for Java 8. The closest thing to `FileOutputStream` that I can find is `FileInputStream` - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/b5c6ff776bee/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c

Comment: @MateuszPrzybyla It looks to be the same in Java 8.https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/native/java/io/FileOutputStream_md.c#L63 I searched on the method name.

Comment: are solaris definitions packaged for ubuntu amd64 distribution of jdk?

Comment: @MateuszPrzybyla Some classes were just labelled "native" http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/68dc2c198948/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c  but this one appears to assume "solaris" works for any Unix.

Comment: OK, it all starts to make sense but I'm still missing one puzzle - is there anywhere inside Linux/shared definitions a reference to `FileOutputStream` definition from solaris?

Comment: @MateuszPrzybyla this is determined by the Makefiles as to which `.c` to compile.

Comment: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/fbf3cabc9e3b/jdk/make/common/Defs-linux.gmk#l53 shows that linux uses the same sources as solaris